# How do I calculate the runtime of two nested loops with the big-O Notation?

Tags: algorithm, runtime, big-o

So I want to figure out the runtime of the following algorithm (in pseudocode):

```pascal
Algorithm(N):
    int i = n;
    int j;
    new Array sum[(n + 1) / 2];
    while i > 1 do
        j = i;
        while j < n do
            for k = 0; k < n; k = k + 2 do
                sum[k / 2] = sum[(k / 2) - 1] + k;
            end
            j = j * 2;
        end
        i = i / 2;
    end 
    return sum
```

Comment: If `n` is 256, the values of `i` are `256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2`. When `i` is 256, the `j` loop executes 0 times. When `i` is 128, the `j` loop executes 1 time. And so on. So the `j` loop runs a total of `1+2+3+4+5+6+7` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop will make <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub> iterations.

The middle loop will make 0 iterations the first time it runs, then 1, then 2, then 3, ... until <sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub>. This is a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), and so the middle loop will have a total number of executions that is equal to:

<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub>(<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub> + 1) / 2

The inner loop will always make the same number of iterations for each iteration of the middle loop, as it is independent of the value of  or : it is  / 2. So in total it will have the following number of iterations:

<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub>(<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub> + 1) / 4

There are two ways time complexity is calculated with respect to arithmetic calculations:

1. In a first approach we assume that all involved arithmetic calculations are performed in constant time (like addition, decrement, division by 2, and multiplication by 2), and so we can derive the following asymptotic order:

   O(<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub>(<sub>⌊</sub>log<sub><sub>2</sub></sub><sub>⌋</sub> + 1) / 4) = O(log²)
2. A more purist approach does not assume that arithmetic calculations are performed in constant time, taking into account that integers are not stored in limited words (like 64-bit), but can be arbitrary long. This means that the above-mentioned arithmetic calculations have a O(log) time complexity. So then we must add that factor, as these are used in the body of the inner loop:

   O(log³)

The assignment should specify which of the two approaches is to be used.